# Sails.js model updatedAt (updated_at) not auto updating

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

**Expected Behavior:**

After successfully updating a record using [.update()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update), the record's `updated_at` field should auto-update to the current time.

*Note: I changed the [autoUpdatedAt](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?autoupdatedat) setting (also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987551/is-it-possible-to-rename-createdat-and-updatedat-in-sails-js-waterline)) using `autoUpdatedAt: 'updated_at'` in config.models so the field is titled `updated_at` instead of `updatedAt`. It should still have the same functionality I would assume.*

**Actual Behavior:**

The model successfully updates, but it does not update the `updated_at` field.

**Code Run:**

```
model.update(primary, data)
.then(function updateCB(updated){
  // error handling
  sails.log('Updated successfully');
  sails.log(updated);
});
```

**Questions:**

- Why is this?
- How do I fix this?

---

**Result: Issue for Sails**

I was able to reproduce it on a new project, so it looks like it's a problem with sails. Issue link: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3821

See my answer below for more info.

Comment: Can you show what the `updated_at` attribute looks like inside your model file?

Comment: It's not an attribute in the model file; it's a sails level command to rename the autoUpdatedAt attribute - I linked it in the note.

Comment: ah, there's your problem :)

Comment: Haha I wish it were that simple :) But renaming it shouldn't undo its functionality. The `create_at` works perfectly.

Comment: I updated my answer with a third option, inspired by what I do with `bcrypt` actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't answer the 'why' I tried the same thing and ran into the same issue. As for how to fix it -

I made it an attribute in my model file for any models I wanted it on and filled it out like so:

```
    updated_at:{
        type: 'datetime',
        defaultsTo: function(){return new Date();}
    }
```

With the column in my DB (mysql in this case) being set to `NOT NULL` and `DATETIME` and set to update `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on UPDATE`.

You can also put this in code if you don't have access to your db, just before your update call:

```
data.updated_at = new Date();
model.update(primary,data)....
```

That will accomplish the same thing.

This has been the simplest work around I've been able to come up with.

I got thinking about this and I came up with a third option, a model method written like so:

```
attributes:{
    //stuffs
},
beforeUpdate: function(obj, next){
    obj.updated_at = new Date();
    return next(null, obj);
}
```

The `null` in the first position is because as far as I can tell Sails expects an `error` object throughout the call chain so if I passed nothing along then the whole thing crapped out.

Comment: Are you sure that works for updating? It'll set default on create, so that'd work for `created_at`, but I'm not sure about updating. Obviously I'd prefer a config solution, but until Sails fixes it, I'm open to a manual solution.

Comment: @smileham, oh opps, I forgot a step, there are 2 ways to handle this. Since I have full control over my project I did it at the db level but you can do it in code as well see my edit.

Comment: Gotcha. When updating though, does `updated_at` change values? It already has a value from when it was created.

Comment: From the sails docs: defaultsTo - When a record is created, if no value was supplied, the record will be created with the specified defaultsTo value. The supplied value can also be a function that waterline will run while creating the record.

Comment: Got it! The edit makes sense, and thank you for that. Yes, before every time I call `.update()` I can manually set `updated_at`, but that takes away the advantage of an auto update in the first place since it's essentially a static attribute now (and I'd rather not go through all my code to change that). Still two good solutions though - I appreciate it. I'll try the DB route for now.

Comment: @smileham, that's why I went with the DB route as well

Comment: Thanks for that :) I always appreciate multiple solutions to a problem, so you definitely helped me!

Answer (score 0):

**Result: Issue for Sails**

I was able to reproduce it on a new project, so it looks like it's a problem with sails. Issue link: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3821

**Code Run:**

```
Test.create()
.then(function(created){
    sails.log('created');
    sails.log(created);

    Test.update(created, {})
    .then(function(updated){
        sails.log('updated');
        sails.log(updated[0]);

        Test.findOne(updated)
        .then(function(found){
            sails.log('found');
            sails.log(found);

            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```

**Code Result:**

```
debug: created
debug: { createdAt: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  updated_at: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  id: 1 }
debug: updated
debug: { createdAt: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  updated_at: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  id: 1,
  updatedAt: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.698Z' }
debug: found
debug: { createdAt: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  updated_at: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.679Z',
  id: 1,
  updatedAt: '2016-08-25T21:35:46.698Z' }
```

Looks like Sails is still adding an `updatedAt` field which isn't saving to my SQL database.