# Can I (and should I) override the createdAt and updatedAt properties of a Sails.js model?

Tags: sails.js

My Sails application helps monitor the state of our system by monitoring a mix of artifacts (log files, exports, etc) and real-time changes (events, web-hooks, etc).

On various schedules the application reads the artifacts and uses `.findOrCreate()` and `.update()` to update the Sails application state.  Sails then sets the instances `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties to `new Date()` at the time of saving; however I'd like these times to match their source artifact's time-stamp.

How can I override the values for their `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties of a Sails.js model?  And would there be any obvious gotcha's as a result of setting them to a specific timestamp?

Comment: so far I've stored the data in seperate properties, but I'd really prefer to override the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` values.  Also, I'd like to understand the influence of these fields on the system behavior.

Comment: have you seen my answer? If you have any questions, please do ask - be happy to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, you can turn off the defaults.

```
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
```

You are now free to use your own values. You can use the **beforeUpdate** [lifecycle callback](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) (if needed) to add any extra behaviour just prior to updating the model.

For example:

```
beforeUpdate:function(values, next) {
    // do whatever you need here if required.
    // you could just override the default createdAt, updatedAt behaviour
    next();
}
```

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24562385/1882064) answered by a core maintainer here.

If this still doesn't quite address your needs, then leave me a comment below and I will try to update the answer further.

Comment: I've had the chance to play around with this and think it will work.  Setting `autoUpdatedAt: false` removes the property from the model, so then it needs to be added to `attributes` as `updatedAt: 'datetime'`.